# Angular $eval with locals - not quite working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, eval

I'm trying to run a $eval command inside a linking function of a directive but it's not quite working. What I'm trying to run is:

```
function (scope, element, attr) {
    ...
    var date = ....... // string that can be parsed to date
    scope.$eval(attr.myModel + "=new Date(d)", {d: date});
}
```

"date" is a string that is calculated and saved as a string (that can be parsed to Date object easily). The code fails when trying to run "new Date(d)". The "attr.myModel" is parsed on the scope successfully but the "d" var is not parsed on the object I'm passing to $eval.

(using Angular 1.5)

The error message from Angular is:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is an unexpected token at column 36 of the expression [formCtrl.selections.earlyStart=new Date(d)] starting at [Date(d].
```

I tried passing the local object the Date constructor as well but it didn't change much

Thanks!

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"*. Error message (which you didn't post here) explains what you are doing wrong. Also why do you even need `$eval`, you should not use it in this case.

Comment: Included is the error message

Comment: `$eval` is not `eval`. It evaluates Angular expressions, not arbitrary (and potentially harmful) JS code.

Comment: @estus - I'm aware and this is what I need in this case. If I had other solution here I'd choose it.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve it:

```
scope.$eval(attributes.myModel + "=d", {d: new Date(date)});
```